# TextView border colour not set to yellow after calling it

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am learning Android and have created a TableLayout with two rows in an Activity called PlayActivity. In each row I put TextViews that I want to have borders in the colours with suffix `Edge` given in `colors.xml`. Everything works fine except that the `YELLOW` (text) colour does not lead to yellow border colour in `tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_edge)`.

I am making a game where the user ends up in the PlayActivity and draws a number of tiles from a "bag". These tiles have a number in the colours in capitals (e.g. `YELLOW`) and a border in another colour defined in the `colors.xml` file. I checked whether my yellow_edge colour is opaque and it is. I don't understand why the other colours work while this one does not. Can anyone please help find my mistake? The output I get is this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWGME.png)

My Tile Class:

```
import android.graphics.Color.rgb
val BLUE: Int = rgb(0, 0, 255)
val RED: Int = rgb(255, 0, 0)
val YELLOW: Int = rgb(255,235,0)
val BLACK: Int = rgb(0, 0, 0)


class Tile(val col: Int = 0, val num: Int = 0){
    val name = "$col $num"
}
```

How I instantiate my tiles:

```
class PlayActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val COLOURS = listOf(BLUE, RED, YELLOW, BLACK)
    val NUMBERS = IntRange(1, 13)
    lateinit var nameTv: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play)
        val pack = makeTiles()
        nameTv = findViewById(R.id.nameTextView)
        val player = Player("Jack", plankGrid, this)
        nameTv.text = player.name
        player.drawTiles(14, pack)

    }
    private fun makeTiles(): MutableList<Tile>{
        val a = mutableListOf<Tile>()
        var count = 0
        for (value in COLOURS) {
            for (number in NUMBERS) {
                count += 1
                val tile = Tile(value, number)
                a.add(tile)
            }
        }
        a.shuffle()
        return a
    }
}
```

`activity_play.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:context=".PlayActivity">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/app_name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="440dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" android:orientation="horizontal" android:gravity="top|start"
            android:id="@+id/plankGrid">

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/row1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"/>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/row2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    </TableLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My class where I fill the TableLayout with TextViews:

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TableLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_play.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_play.view.*


class Player(val name: String = "Jack",
             private var table: TableLayout,
             private val ct: Activity,
             private var count: Int = 0) {

    fun drawTiles(n: Int, pack: MutableList<Tile>) {
        for (i in IntRange(0, n-1)) {
            addTileToTable(pack[i])
            count += 1
        }
    }

    fun addTileToTable(tile: Tile) {
        val tv = TextView(ct)
        tv.setTextColor(tile.col)
        tv.textSize = 24.toFloat()
        tv.text =  tile.num.toString()
        tv.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY
        tv.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        tv.width = table.layoutParams.width / 15
        tv.height = table.layoutParams.height / 2
        when (tile.col) {  // check colours and then set the border around the textview to that colour
            BLUE -> tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_edge)
            RED -> tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_edge)
            YELLOW -> tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_edge) // this is where it apparently goes wrong
            BLACK -> tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_edge)
        }
        if (count <= 15) {
            table.row1.addView(tv)
        }
        if (count in 16..30) {
            table.row2.addView(tv)
        }
    }
}
```

`colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
    <color name="bluebck">#2882D1</color>
    <color name="blueEdge">#004780</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="redEdge">#E70000</color>
    <color name="yellowEdge">#FFEB3B</color>
    <color name="blackEdge">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

`yellow_edge.xml` and for comparison also `blue_edge.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/yellowEdge"/>
            <padding android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/blueEdge"/>
            <padding android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: are you sure that title.col is yellow? How does your yellow_edge look like?

Comment: Could you also show the `Tile` class?

Comment: @ReneFerrari thanks for the suggestion. I just checked with debugger and it turns out tile.col is -8448 while YELLOW is  -5376.  However, they also don't match for the other lines in the `when` block.  I will update the question with yellow_edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so after creating a new project using the code you provided I have found out the following:

You define your colors as constants which you than have to import in `Activity` and `Player` class.

Now my assumption is that in one of those classes you import `YELLOW` wrong. You defined this color yourself, but **`import android.graphics.Color.YELLOW`** also exists. I believe that you have mistakenly imported this instead of just `import YELLOW`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to find that out ! I tried your solution, and in doing so I found the real source of the bug. It turns out that that import was not the problem (I didn't import the colours at all but used global variables), but I had accidentally redefined the colours inside the PlayActivity class and somehow the yellow colour was not recognised in the `when` statement inside the `Player` class. It works now at least. Thanks again for your time :)

Comment: Glad it still helped! I really thought I had found the solution hehe ;P